Master thesis opportunities in High Energy Physics in Germany for Indian/International Students
My final year will start in coming August, and our department allows us to go anywhere in the world for an MSc thesis. I wish to do a one-year (min. 8 months) thesis in Germany in high energy physics theory with a stipend. The maximum I can afford is a visa and a plane ticket. I don't know where to apply and where my chances are high to get selected. I've tried contacting professors here, in India, but positive replies were 4%, and I could not contact those under whom I really wish to do my thesis.
Is there a way to get selected for reputed institutes in Germany with a stipend? My Gate rank is under 150, and my grade point average is also under the top 5 in the class. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The stipend is going to be the critical point here. You might want to put that into the title, as it is absolutely not the standard for MSc in Germany.

Supervising MA students is work. The university hires a professor to do that work for students enrolled in that university. This makes sense: the university only gets money from/for its own students. This is what all the bureaucracy around exchange programmes is all about. Exchange agreements between universities look something like: university A promises to take care of x students from university B if university B also takes care of x students from university A.
Some governments also reserve some money for students who want to participate but come from a university that is not attractive enough to sign such an exchange agreement.
So, your first step is to figure out if your university or country has signed exchange agreements. If not you can look for aid. In Germany a big part is organized through the DAAD.
